# How to enforce <DIV> tag to use the free space in a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a sample website to learn CSS and HTML. Have created a horizontal nav bar, a side nav bar, and a welcome message on the top of the page. And when any of the links are clicked the corresponding Html file will be loaded onto the 'mainContent' . All are working as expected except the 'mainContent'  is not occupying the remaining space of the page. Please advise me on what is missing.

```css
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  background-color: #111;
  margin-left:160px;
  width: 90%;
  height:10%;
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: Green;
  color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
  color: White;
}

/* The sidebar menu */
.sidenav {
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 80%; /* Full-height: remove this if you want "auto" height */
    width: 160px; /* Set the width of the sidebar */
    position: absolute; /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */
    z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
    top: 1000; /* Stay at the top */
    left: 0;
    background-color: #00A555; /* Black */
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    display: block;
    font-family: sans-serif; 
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style page content */
.main {
  margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidebar */
  /*padding: 0px 10px;*/
  /*top: auto;
  position: static;*/
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding-top: 20px;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>XYZ Hostel</title>
    <style>
        li {
            display: inline;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="divCss.css">
<body>
    <script>
        function lurl(page) {
            let node = document.getElementById('mainContent');
            let url = '<object type="text/html" data=' + "\""+ page + "\"" + '></object>';
            node.innerHTML = url;
        }
    </script>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="Welcome">
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <img alt="Hostel" src="hostel1.webp" width="200" height="100">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <div>
                            <h2 style="color: black; font-family: Lucida Calligraphy; font-style: black;">Welcome to XYZ Hostel</h2>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="topnav">
                <ul style="list-style: none; padding-left: 0;" >
                    <li><a class="active" href="#" onclick="lurl('Student_Home.html')">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="lurl('Student_2.html')">Login</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="lurl('Students_Teacher_3.html')">Room Details</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="lurl('Students_Marks.html')">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menuOption">
            <!-- Side navigation -->
            <div class="sidenav">
                <ul style="list-style: none; padding-left: 0">
                    <li><a class="active" href="#" onclick="lurl('Student_Home.html')">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="lurl('Student_2.html')">Login</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="lurl('Students_Teacher_3.html')">Room Details</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="lurl('Students_Marks.html')">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainContent" class="main">
                     
            <!-- iframe id="contentPage" height="600" width="1200" style="border: 0">
                
            </iframe -->
    </div>
    
    <footer>
        Thank you   
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxqHB.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I added the entire content just to let the experts understand the code easier. Will take care of this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your question i don't understand 100% what you are trying to do.
Because you are loading some extra content, i can't really see it here on the snippet.

But i think something like this would work:

```css
.grid {
  --grid-sidebar-width: 160px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: var(--grid-sidebar-width) 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" ". topbar" "aside main";
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  grid-column: 1/ -1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: var(--grid-sidebar-width) 1fr;
  grid-area: header;
}

.header__title {
  text-align: right;
}

.topbar {
  grid-area: topbar;
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

.topbar__nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.aside {
  grid-area: aside;
  background-color: green;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.main__content {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <header class="header">
    <p>Logo</p>
    <p class="header__title">Welcome to xyz hostel</p>
  </header>
  <div class="topbar">
    <nav>
      <ul class="topbar__nav">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Content A</li>
        <li>Content B</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <aside class="aside">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 3</li>
        <li>Link 3</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </aside>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="main__content">
      <p>You content goes here</p>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

This allows you to create the basic layout (grid) for the page without needing to place any elements with position absolute or by giving them hacky margins.

I didn't pay much attention to any other styles, just the grid layout.

This html and css create a grid with two columns:

- a left column of 160px (defined by the `--grid-sidebar-width` variable)
- a right column that takes the rest of the available space

You then just need to place your page elements on the grid areas where you want to show them.

The content you load with JS can be placed inside the `main__content` div.

Here is some more information about using CSS grid:

- [CSS Grid on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid)
- [Grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids)
- [CSS Grid Area](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area)
- [CSS Template Columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns)
- [CSS Template Rows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows)

Comment: Thank you Boguz for the  detailed explanation. "From your question i don't understand 100% what you are trying to do" - Please check the uploaded .PNG for more clarity (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxqHB.png). I want the 'mainContent' <DIV> to occupy the remaining free space in the page. Am dynamically loading an HTML page into this 'mainContent' <DIV>.

Comment: @Ram isn't this what my example is doing? That `main__content` takes the free space

Comment: I tried your example too as: <main class="main">
   <div class="main__content">
    <p id="mc"></p>
   </div>
  </main>     -- And in the java script I am using this id 'mc' to load the html page. I got the same result.   let node = document.getElementById('mc');
   let url = '<object type="text/html" data=' + "\""+ page + "\"" + '></object>';
   node.innerHTML = url;...... I am not sure am I still missing anything here.

Comment: do you want to load a lot of content? Maybe it would be better to just load all the content when the page loads and the hide the ones you don't want to show. Then you can just toggle the visibility of the correct content with JS

Comment: do you want to load a lot of content? - For each click on the menu items the relevant page will be loaded. Toggling the visibility - Yes. At the moment I have implemented this solution. But going forward it may not be the expected behaviour. Thanks a lot for your help.